# How to make my login form check SQL table if details are correct in C#

Tags: c#

Hello my fellow stackoverflow users!

I am doing an assignment which is a website that will allow user to register, login, add a item and place a bid. I have made a registration for and used SqlDataSource to insert that information into a table called Buyer or Seller depending on what form they choose (there are two on a page) Let's focus on Buyer

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buyer] (
[BuyerID]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Username]     NCHAR (15)    NOT NULL,
[Password]     NCHAR (15)    NOT NULL,
[FirstName]    NCHAR (15)    NOT NULL,
[LastName]     NCHAR (15)    NOT NULL,
[Address]      NCHAR (30)    NOT NULL,
[EmailAddress] NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[Postcode]     NVARCHAR (8)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BuyerID] ASC)
```

);

So this is the buyer table, after they register they are taken to a login page which again has 2 login forms. Here comes the problem, on login form they are asked for username and password and what would I have to do for it to search this buyer table to see if username and password are correct and if yes, take them to different page and if not give them a message "your details are incorrect".

Please try to keep it simple as I am beginner when it comes to C#, and thanks for any help.

Source code for login page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <div class="buyer">
            <h1>Buyer</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
            <br />
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Username], [Password] FROM [Buyer] WHERE (([Username] = @Username) AND ([Password] = @Password))">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Username" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="Password" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click1" Text="Login As Buyer" />

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
    </div>
          <div class="seller">
              <h1>Seller</h1>


 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
        <br />
        <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login as Seller" />
</div>  
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add source code to your question.

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: I have no clue I am using visual basic studio 2013 with basic setup i just clicked new website and started to use it

Comment: With asp.NET, there exists the .aspx code, which is the code you've shown us.  This generates the HTML that is ultimately sent to the client.  We need to see your CodeBehind.  The filename will be something like login.aspx.cs.  We do NOT need to see login.aspx.designer.cs

Comment: if you have no idea what I'm talking about, then that explains why you can't figure out how to do your assignment....because you haven't seen the proper file yet!

Comment: ok I have added it to main post. It does not bring anything as well it is supposed to be simple

Comment: so basically when I click a button I want to see if the entered details match database deatils, if they do redirect them to another page and if they don't well then tough ;p

Comment: ASP.NET comes with [login controls built in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). Do try to use them as they will solve a lot of common problems without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: for some reason they do not work correctly, even teacher have tried this and seems there is a problem with either that login control or from university network side. Technicians can't fix it -,-

Comment: anyone has any ideas?